# How to make a webpage unsearchable?

Tags: seo, privacy

Is there a way to make a webpage made as a resume unsearchable by any search engine?

The aim is to only share the page with those who have the link.

Comment: Put it in Dropbox and share the link.

Answer (score 11):

There are more points and I'd prefer to apply them all:

As *Daniel* stated in his answer:

**1)** In you website location `http://example.com/robots.txt`

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

> This means: For all robots/crawlers, do not allow to index any URI of
>   this  location.

**2) If** **robots.txt accidentally skipped or broken**, in the HTML source code on **all** of your pages you could have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
    ...
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```

> This means: If accessed this page, do not index this page, even do not crawl its links - in other words - stop and go away from here.

**3) If** your website is **not dedicated to be public**, crate a password in .htaccess, if using Apache for example. So as the user will try to enter the site, he'll need a username and password.

**4) If** your website has been **already indexed** in some way and you want to disable it to be searchable for public, you could remove the web URLS from Google's index using Google Webmaster Tools:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called robots.txt in the root of your website with the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

This will prevent all major search engines from indexing the site.

Comment: yes, I had seen this solution before. But that belongs to long time ago. Does it still work?